# Why isn't Solr indexing my docs?

Tags: solr

This is what I have in my schema.xml:

```
<fields>
  <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
  <field name="about" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
  <field name="music" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
  <field name="movies" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
  <field name="occupation" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />  
  <field name="text" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
</fields>

<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
```

And this is the doc I posted:

```
<add>
    <doc>
        <field name="id">abc123</field>     
        <field name="about">I am somebody</field>
        <field name="music">pop</field>
        <field name="movies">titanic</field>
        <field name="occupation">web dev</field>
    </doc>
</add>
```

The doc was pushed out to Solr just fine, when I search in Solr Admin using the `*:*` it shows my doc like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<response>
  <lst name="responseHeader">
    <int name="status">0</int>
    <int name="QTime">1</int>
    <lst name="params">
      <str name="indent">on</str>
      <str name="start">0</str>
      <str name="q">*:*</str>
      <str name="version">2.2</str>
      <str name="rows">10</str>
    </lst>
  </lst>
  <result name="response" numFound="1" start="0">
    <doc>
      <str name="about">I am somebody</str>
      <str name="id">abc123</str>
      <str name="movies">titanic</str>
      <str name="music">pop</str>
      <str name="occupation">web dev</str>
    </doc>
  </result>
</response>
```

yet when I search using a keyword that is clearly in the doc, such as "titanic" or "web" no results show:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<response>
  <lst name="responseHeader">
    <int name="status">0</int>
    <int name="QTime">1</int>
    <lst name="params">
      <str name="indent">on</str>
      <str name="start">0</str>
      <str name="q">titanic</str>
      <str name="version">2.2</str>
      <str name="rows">10</str>
    </lst>
  </lst>
  <result name="response" numFound="0" start="0"/>
</response>
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Maybe is an obvious question, but did you do a commit?

Comment: If \*:\* shows it then it's been committed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks as if you need to specify a field name (q=movies:titanic) or set the default field in schema.xml.

Comment: btw what if I wanted to search for a keyword across all fields, not just movies. How should the query look? Something like: "about,music,movies,occupation:titanic" ?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your search will work if you specify a field name.  If you want to be able to search without specifying a field name, you need to specify `<defaultSearchField>` in your schema.xml.